# Actionscripts 3 GET/POST to server with content type defination

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, animate-cc

I need to get and send request from/to server. i found a code in this site but it not working for me. api url is true and i can get data "**{"out":355}**" from firefox.

```
import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;

var request:URLRequest=new URLRequest();
request.url="******************************************"
request.requestHeaders=[new URLRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")];
request.method=URLRequestMethod.GET;
var loader:URLLoader=new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, receive);
loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, notAllowed);
loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, notFound);
loader.load(request);

function receive(event:Event):void
{
    var myResults=JSON.decode(event.target.data);
    trace(myResults);
}
```

ERROR:

> Scene 1, Layer 'MAIN PAGE', Frame 1, Line 15, Column 25   1061: Call to
>   a possibly undefined method decode through a reference with static
>   type Class.

Comment: There's no such thing as `JSON.decode()` That's what the error message is telling you. Why didn't you just simply read [the Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html) ? JSON has 2 methods `stringify`and `parse`.

Comment: why this work "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111193/get-and-parse-json-in-actionscript" but mine not work?

Comment: This code is easier than Adobe documentation codes.

Comment: I assume your code doesn't work because `JSON` is already a top level of AS3 and gets imported by default. So even if you import the old, deprecated stuff, you will still use the new stuff by default.

Comment: What do you mean? You just have to change one line, everything else stays the same.

Comment: OK, tell me which line and how i change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;

var request:URLRequest=new URLRequest();
request.url="******************************************"
request.requestHeaders=[new URLRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")];
request.method=URLRequestMethod.GET;
var loader:URLLoader=new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, receive);
loader.load(request);

function receive(event:Event):void
{
    trace(event.target.data);
    var json: Object = JSON.parse(event.target.data);
    trace("json.out = ", json.out);
}
```

Result:

{"out":352}

json.out =  352

Comment: Working fine. how to POST data?